# How to send or assign Jquery Variable value to php variable?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I wanted to get a img src to php variable when a user clicks it so i used jquery function to get img src when user clicks that image.Below jquery is for fetching img src

```
$("img").click(function() {
    var ipath = $(this).attr('src');
})
```

now i tried something like this to get the ipath value to php variable

```
$.ajax({ type:'POST', url: 'sample.php',
 dataType: 'HTML', data: dataString,
 success: function(data)
{
 } 
});
});
```

I'm not sure about using Ajax correctly can anyone help with Ajax function to get this done? 
Thank you.

Comment: What errors are you getting while using this ?

Comment: no errors..i don't know to get this value to a php vaiable in sample.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make ajax call when img is clicked for example:

```
$(function (){
   $("#myimg").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: { param: $(this).attr('src'); }
      }).done(function( msg ) {
             alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
     });
  });
}
```

**html code**

```
<img src="http://yourimage.jpg" alt="image" id="myimg" />
```

in **some.php** use

```
 echo $_POST['param'];
```

to get value and if you used `type:GET` you should use then `$_GET` to obtain value.

Comment: Should i use form action and method before this script?

Comment: you don't have to because there is no form submitted only click action :) I've edited with html code. When you use #myimg it affects only item where id="myimg" if you used on $("img") it will affect every image you click.

Comment: I'm working with $(Img) alone.after clicking it when i check sample.php file its showing error Error suppression ignored for Notice: Undefined index: param

Comment: because you just call it as some.php without GET params if you called it `some.php?param=asdfasdf` there will be no notice. If you use $_POST then don't open some.php just see what message is alerted in js. Your ajax request if there are no errors in javascript will work with no problem. These are basics really. Also `$(Img)` is incorrect it should be `$('img')`

Comment: Thanks Robert.its saying Data Saved, now how can i access Saved Data in sample.php

Comment: if you put in sample.php `echo $_POST['param']` it should say `data saved your_attr_src_here` there are other options too read about json datatype and `json_encode()` php function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30746/discussion-between-raj-and-robert)

Answer (score 3):

please try this. hope it will help.

```
$("img").click(function() {
   var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');

    jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',                    
            url:'somepage.php',            
            data:{"imgSrc" : imgSrc},
            dataType:'json',                
            success: function(rs)
            {
                alert("success");
            }
        });  
});
```

try to fetch "imgSrc" on "somepage.php" as "$_post["imgSrc"].

Answer (score 1):

As written [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) you should do it as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'sample.php',
    dataType : 'HTML',
    data : {
        param : 'value'
    },
    success : function(data) {
    }
});
});
```

and then in php your variable will be in `$_POST['param']`

Comment: success call back function is working,but in sample.php i get error **Notice: Undefined index: param**

Comment: Use firebug+firephp to debug this

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img").click(function() {
    var ipath = $(this).attr('src');
    $.ajax({ type:'POST', url: 'sample.php',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        data : {
            path: ipath 
        },
        success: function(data)
        {

        } 
    });//end of ajax

})//end of click
```

You can get this value in php script as `$_POST['path']`

Answer (score 1):

this should help

```
$("img").click(function() {
    jQuery.post("some.php",{param:$(this).attr('src')},function(data){
      console.log(data);
    },'html');
});
```

in some.php

do a `print_r($_POST);` to understand how to pull the needed information/data

Comment: this displays array()

Comment: you possibly used print rather then print_r you should have receive something around these lines.    Array
(
    [param] => http://api.jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery-ui.png
)

Answer (score 1):

try like this -

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function() {
        var ipath = $(this).attr('src');

        var dataString = 'imagePath='+ipath;
        var sendRquest = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'action.php',
            data: dataString
        });

        sendRquest.done(function(responseData) {
            // your code here
            alert(responseData);
        });

        sendRquest.fail(function(xmlhttprequest,textstatus,responseData) {
            // your code here
            alert('failed');
        });

        sendRquest.always(function(){
            // your code here
            alert('done');  
        });

    });

    $("img").click(function() {
        var ipath = $(this).attr('src');
        $('#divid').load('action.php?imagePath='+ipath);

        //if trigger required
        $('#divid').load('action.php?imagePath='+ipath, function() {
          alert('Load was performed.');
        });
    });
});
```

in action.php

```
<?php
   echo $_POST['imagePath'];
   // if you are using load function then
   echo $_GET['imagePath'];
?>
```

Comment: alert coming with <font size>,<tr>,etc

Comment: first see what you are sending. try alert(ipath); before sending to ajax

Answer (score 1):

**Ajax Function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
    $("#img").click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    //OR// var src = $("#img").attr('src');
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "myfile.php",
            data: {imgsrc: src}
          }).done(function(data) {
                 alert(data);
         });
      });
});
</script>
```

**myfile.php**

```
<?php
echo $_GET['imgsrc']; exit;
?>
```

Comment: Getting error in sample.php **Notice: Undefined index: imgsrc**

Comment: seems like you have not changed ajax function properly! i recommend you to copy and paste and plsease notice that page name is myfile.php not sample.php! try this and if still it doesnot work let me know i will try my best to fix it! @raj

Comment: In the url i gave sample.php only, even though it showing error in sample.php

Comment: @raj I have just copy past my working script and this is absolutly functioning! at first i also get same error message later on i found my mistake i was get imgsrc in POST instead of GET in php file!
Please check your method type(GET/POST) and url. :)

Comment: am getting imgsrc when i click the image but not in sample.php file