# How to send or assign Jquery Variable value to php variable?

Tags: php, jquery

I got the answer from this post [[How to send or assign Jquery Variable value to php variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784936/how-to-send-or-assign-jquery-variable-value-to-php-variable]) but somehow my PHP can not get the value passed from Jquery
this is html code

```
<a href="random.php" id="comp1">comp1</a>
<a href="random.php" id="comp2">comp2</a>
<a href="random.php" id='comp3'>comp3</a>
```

Jquery code

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'random.php',
        data: {name:$(this).attr('id')
    }           
    }).done(function(msg){
        alert(msg)
    })
})
```

and PHP code

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['name']  ;
echo $id;

?>
```

Comment: try to use success and error handlers instead of the .done() thing, I've never seen it used this way.

Comment: actually, it still alerts msg but PHP doesn't echo $id

Comment: Open developer tools and see the request that you actually send to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you might want to use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the default behavior of a hyperlink.
Because your `<a` tag has a link to `random.php` which is to jump to another page.

```
 $('a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     .....
 }
```

Your code could go like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'random.php',
        data: {name:$(this).attr('id')}           
    }).done(function(msg){
     alert(msg);
  });
});
```

The document of `event.preventDefault()` is here:
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

---

It might not be the main problem but you don't have to write a `href` to the `random.php` like this:

```
  <a href="random.php" id="comp1">comp1</a>
```

I guess you could go like this:

```
  <a href="#" id="comp1">comp1</a>
```

Or like this:

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="comp1">comp1</a>
```

You might want to read this page:

[Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to prevent onclick action to go to the that page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "random.php",
            data: {"name" : $(this).attr('id')}
        }).done(function( msg ) {
           alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
       });
    return false; // prevent from browsing that page
    });
});
```

Comment: can you tell me what my error is ? because I have been checking for errors but I haven't seen anything

Comment: sorry my bad, on my local computer i forgot to add the `}` , you just need to add return false to prevent from browsing and going to the `random.php` page.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="comp1">comp1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="comp2">comp2</a>
<a href="javascript:;" id='comp3'>comp3</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a').click(function(){        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'random.php',
        data: { name: $(this).attr('id') }
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( msg );
    });
});
```

Use `href="javascript:;"` attr, or `e.preventDefault();` inside event handler, to prevent the link executing.