# How to get Jquery value in php

Tags: php, html, ajax

**I want to grab the return Gameresult value in php which came with the Jquery id call**

The html tag

```
<p id="gameresult">

</p>
```

**i want to grab the value into php which will be appended here**

the Jquerypart :

```
this.enter = function() {
        var obj = g;
        g.platform.soundManager.gameover.play();
        var result = $('<ul><li>You type '+g.score.score+' characters in '+g.time.time+' seconds.</li><li><u>Your speed</u> : about ' + Math.floor( (Math.ceil(g.score.score / 5) / g.time.time) * 60) +' words per minutes!</li></ul>');
        g.platform.stopAnim();
        this.hideMenu();
        $('#gameresult').append(result);
        this.showState(this.screen);
```

below is the link:

[bubbletyping.base.pk](http://bubbletyping.base.pk)

just play the game at the top left corner
for demo..

Comment: There's no ajax there. You can tell by `$.ajax()`, `$.post()`, and `$.get()` not making any appearance.

Comment: Where is ajax ? Please tell.

Comment: Sorry my mistake its Jquery...can you suggest me any sloution

Comment: So, you want to return a value from JQuery to HTML ?  Because I don't see any php either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the $() stuff around your result string.  Also, you should check to make sure g.time.time isn't zero before division.

```
var speed = (g.time.time === 0 ? 0 : Math.floor( (Math.ceil(g.score.score / 5) / g.time.time) * 60))
var result = '<ul><li>You type '+g.score.score+' characters in '+g.time.time+' seconds.</li><li><u>Your speed</u> : about ' + speed +' words per minutes!</li></ul>;
```

[Here is a JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rmhbhuba/)

Comment: Thanks devlin carnate but what i am trying to get the result from the Jquery part or html part and assign it to a php variable..how can i do that..Thanks For the help

Comment: You would do that using AJAX.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586471/how-to-send-or-assign-jquery-variable-value-to-php-variable